# Como fazer um update no firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

Boa noite

Tenho uma função que cadastra uma solicitação no firebase:

```
async function handleSubmit(){
    
      let endereco = `${route.params?.local.local[0]} ${route.params?.local.local[1]}, ${route.params?.local.local[2]} - ${route.params?.local.local[3]}.`
      console.log(endereco)

      let nome = user.nome;
      let key = await firebase.database().ref('solicitacoes').push().key;
        await firebase.database().ref('solicitacoes').child(key).set({
            uriImg: uriImg.uri,
            local: endereco,
            servico: servico,
            descricao: descricao,
            date: format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
            situacao: 'Aberto',
            solicitante: nome
        });
          setUriImg({});
          setServico('');
          setDescricao('');
          navigation.navigate('home');
  }
```

Preciso fazer uma função que altera apenas a situação de "Aberto" para "Fechado".
Lembrando que quero fazer isso apenas para um item, não para todas as solicitações já cadastradas.

Answer (score 0):

```
let chave = route.params?.data.key; //pagando a chave selecionada na tela anterior

function handleFechar(){
  firebase.database().ref('solicitacoes').child(chave).set({
    date: data,
    descricao: descricao,
    local: local,
    servico: servico,
    situacao: "Fechado",
    solicitante: solicitante,
    uriImg: imagem
  })
  alert("A solicitação foi fechada!")
  setState(false)
  
}

function handleAbrir(){

  if (situacao === "Fechado"){
    setState(false);
    firebase.database().ref('solicitacoes').child(chave).set({
      date: data,
      descricao: descricao,
      local: local,
      servico: servico,
      situacao: "Aberto",
      solicitante: solicitante,
      uriImg: imagem
    })
  }
  alert("A solicitação foi Aberta!")
  setState(true);
}
```